# Does the g++ stringstream constructor have a critical section?

Tags: c++, g++, openmp

I was looking over some source code that used openmp to parallelize a loop. Inside the loop a stringstream was constructed and a few characters were written to it, and at the end the characters were retrieved using stringstream::str(). The parallelization of the loop didn't seem to make much difference to performance, until the stringstream constructor was moved out of the loop and replaced with calls to stringstream::clear().

Is there a critical section or some other blocking mechanism inside the stringstream constructor? If so, is that documented somewhere? The code was compiled with g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: It needs to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroying a `stringstream` object destroys its memory buffer. You are seeing the effects of heap allocation inside the loop.

Calling `clear` does not free any memory. It allows the loop to reuse the buffer.

Comment: Is there documentation on what memory buffer is allocated?

Comment: @BenFulton See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream . The buffer is inside a `std::string`, hence the name.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stringstream` constructor calls the default constructor of `std::locale`.

This is because it inherits from `std::ios_base` and such types must call `std::basic_ios::init()` (as described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/ios_base). This call honors the post-condition that `getloc()` will then return a copy of a default constructed `std::local` object (as described here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init) - therefore `std::locale()` must be called within `std::stringstream`'s constructor.

The `std::local` constructor will result in a reference count increment on the facets relating to the current global locale. (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale).

> both the locale reference count and each facet reference count are updated in thread-safe manner, similar to std::shared_ptr

The increment has to be atomic as it is modifying shared state.

Depending on the standard library implementation you are using, this could explain why you did not see the performance increase you were expecting.